# [angular]: can't console.log insde forEach

Tags: angular

Here's this code:

```
@Input() public neededDocuments: NeededDocumentsDto[];
  
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.neededDocuments);
    this.neededDocuments.forEach((x: NeededDocumentsDto) => console.log(x));
  }
```

The first console.log is OK, the content of the array is displayed.
The second console.log inside the forEach diplays nothing.

EDIT:
[image]

Why ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the console output

Answer (score 0):

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.neededDocuments);
    this.neededDocuments.forEach((x: NeededDocumentsDto) => {console.log(x)});
  }
```

I mean this will solve your problem

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work, I've already tried that